# ethernet not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: internet

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 and have been having issues connecting to the internet.  Wifi is working nut ethernet connection not working.The connection information shows connected but still internet not working.
please help to solve this problem.
 how to solve it?

Comment: Does explicitly setting dns to something like 8.8.8.8 help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if it reaches your router via ethernet: `ping 192.168.1.1` (it might have different IP, check your connection informations).

Then try some external servers, like: `ping ubuntu.com`.

You can also try reseting iptables:

```
## set default policies to let everything in
iptables --policy INPUT   ACCEPT;
iptables --policy OUTPUT  ACCEPT;
iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT;

## start fresh
iptables -Z; # zero counters
iptables -F; # flush (delete) rules
iptables -X; # delete all extra chains
```

16.04 also got a firewall, you can also check it (`gufw` - link should be in system settings), but if WiFi works, might not be an issue...