# Ubuntu 12.04 ethernet settings not working

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

I have tampered with my ethernet settings and created a new ethernet connection now I can't access internet on that, which was previously working.
But wireless is working fine.
Here are the results of:

```
ifconfig eth0
```

results of ifconfig eth0:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps something blocked your iptables only for ethernet device, perform a backup `sudo iptables-save > my.iptables.backup` and provide us with an output.

Comment: @Ted    Please can you specify the command for output of my.iptables.backup  .

Comment: Not sure what you mean... It's just the file you want to write your backup to, e.g. `/home/rishabh/my.iptables.backup`. Open it in text editor and paste it into your main post (edit).

Comment: sudo iptables-save > /home/rishabh/my.iptables.backup             gave me an empty file.    @Ted

Comment: Does executing `sudo iptables -L` outputs anything? (I mean at least couple lines like "Chain INPUT..." etc.) Perhaps you could try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/773099/530109 (those iptables commands must be executed with sudo as well). Guess it won't hurt to try that in your case.

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY26d.png)

So this was the output while wired connection 1 was connected.
@Ted .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's very hard to assume much from informations you have provided. I'll describe some ways for obtaining more data and performing a little connection debug. Gather data from all of those ideas and append all of that output to your original question (by "edit" feature).

Deffinately do not make more screenshots of your peculiar terminal(s) (here, for new users apply limits for images & links per post). Select output from terminal simply by using your mouse, then right-click, "Copy" and then right-click in any editor and "Paste" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).

---

Let's commence the investigation (use ethernet device for those):

1. As you have already performed `ifconfig eth0`, you got the following most important data:

   - your device's "MAC Address" (HWaddr **20:47:47:19:52:b8**)
   - your local "IP Address" (inet addr:**192.168.100.35**)
   - your "Subnet Mask" (Mask:**255.255.255.0**)
2. Now we know, that we should expect following "Gateway": **192.168.100.1** (f.e. [This](http://ipcalc.nmonitoring.com) or [That](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/) tool can calculate that, even if it's obvious).
3. Now you can obtain your routes using system's method: `route -n`. The lines with "*Iface | eth0*" and "*Flags | UG*" should show that expected "*Gateway | 192.168.100.1*" (make sure, but save/remember entire output/results anyway)

You didn't tell what type(s) of network(s) are you running (perhaps reveal that secret?). I'm assuming that you are using some home router that also provides wireless connections, that you refered to as working. If so:

4. Open your router's configuration (for most routers you just open: http://192.168.100.1) and investigate whatever you can find there and compare that to what your system outputed (everything from above steps).
5. Additionally check:

   - whether on not "DHCP" is enabled and what's it's range (e.g. *192.168.100.2 - 192.168.100.254*)
   - whether or not there's a "Static DHCP" set specifically for your MAC (*20:47:47:19:52:b8*), if so remove it for now (re-add later, after fixing a problem)
6. Perform a ping from your machine, to see if it properly bounces-back of your router: `ping 192.168.100.1`.
7. If you have different network device/computer, ping that problematic one from it: `ping 192.168.100.35`.
8. Get back to your troubled machine and then try some external servers, like: `ping ubuntu.com`.
9. Make a second attempt to perform a backup of your iptables and check content of outputed file: `sudo iptables-save /home/rishabh/my.iptables.backup`.
10. If it did not returned anything, try `sudo iptables-save` alone and see if it outputs something to your terminal (if it does, perhaps you have a problem with writing to your own, home directory, which would be bizzare for normal Ubuntu)
11. Additionally prove what version of Ubuntu are you actually using by providing output from this command: `lsb_release -a` (your question contains two different versions: *12.04* in title and *14.04* in tags)

---

And now it's time for couple ideas for fixing network connection without actually destroying anything that can't be easily fixed. After performing each one, test if it actually helped. Good method of testing is actually that `ping ubuntu.com` or simply opening any website or whatever else you normally do. Here we go:

1. Try changing your MTU to 1492: `sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1492` (if won't help after that, restore original: `sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 1500`)
2. Open network connection manager (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> & enter `nm-connection-editor` or if it does not open it, search it in your menu or that icon from it's applet that should be on a panel), delete your current ethernet connection(s) (perphaps you even got duplicates?) and add only that one, desired `eth0` again
3. Try configuring IP's manually in this same network manager's connection configuration "IPv4 tab" (phew!), by switching method from "Automatic (DHCP)" to "Manual". Enter there all data you already have and verified are OK ("Local IP", "Subnet Mask", "Gateway").
4. You might also have a firewall while not realizing it. Use a dpkg-method to be 99.9+% sure for `gufw` (that's default in latest Ubuntu's): `dpkg -l gufw`. If you do have that, open it: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> & enter `gufw` (or look for it in menu) and disable it if it's working.
5. Use that dpkg-method one more time: `dpkg -l iptables` to double-check if it still outputs that default, empty one (from your second screen) and try completely flushing iptables and then allow it for everything on default:

> sudo iptables -Z
>
> sudo iptables -F
>
> sudo iptables -X
>
> sudo iptables --policy INPUT ACCEPT
>
> sudo iptables --policy OUTPUT ACCEPT
>
> sudo iptables --policy FORWARD ACCEPT

Run `dpkg -l iptables` again and see if anything had changed.

6. Test different ethernet cable, one broken line does not neccesarily means not establishing connection at all (problem of broken line(s) occurs very rarly, usually in presence of hungry mice)

OK... that's it for today. Try all that and hopefully one of those will help, if not maybe data you gather + experience from trying those fixes (you can also try describing what you have noticed after all those attempts) will give us some additional clues.

---

Additionally, if flushing iptables in some strange way will make everything worse, here's how you restore that backup:

```
sudo iptables-restore < /home/rishabh/my.iptables.backup
```